# How do I use the include directive under IIS

Tags: code

I just took over a local web site and it uses IIS 6. There is a lot of code repeated across all files, and I would like to use some directive to include the same generic code over and over in each file. I tried the directive in the html file, but it does not work. Do I need special configuration in my .htaccess file ? I don't know much IIS, and I am not an administrator on the box. The site is hosted on GoDaddy. Is there something I need to do on my IIS config file for my account ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you mean #include - you need to enable SSI (server side includes) in IIS6+, its in the IIS properties.

ETA - sorry jusr re-read your question, not being the admin you cant do that, but their tech support may be able to?